# Are these sorts of questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and got these points:

1. Write a title that summarizes the specific problem
2. Introduce the problem before you post any code
3. Help others reproduce the problem
4. Include all relevant tags

Now, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056913/how-to-show-line-numbers-in-android-studio). Points 1 and 4 are both correct, but this is not a complete question, right? This is giving something to reference for future users, and it looks like a simple tutorial.

However if anyone Google searches "how to show line numbers in Android Studio", the first result is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751/how-can-i-permanently-have-line-numbers-in-intellij) which
is already a hot topic and had an answer.

I sent a custom flag explaining this. Today, I noticed that my flag was declined, and this was the message I got:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that
>   requires their intervention.

My questions are:

- Are this kinds of posts allowed on Stack Overflow?
- What should I do if see this kind of post?
- If these kinds of posts are not allowed, but my flag was wrong, then which flag should I use?

**EDIT:**

For this question, 3 people had voted to close this question as `Unclear what you are asking`. Is this really not clear?

I really WONDER as I added all details and specifically highlighted my problem.

[image]

Comment: Just because a question isn't as good as it can possibly be, doesn't mean it ought to be flagged. There are improvements I could (and will) make to this meta question, but I'm not even going to downvote for them, because it's Good Enough.

Comment: What is "this type" exactly. Are you asking if it's OK to ask a question I intend and do immediately provide an answer for?

Comment: @ChrisHayes Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I listed points how to ask a good question. The question which i've mentioned doesn't met those condition. So i was asking what should i do if see these posts? you can check out last 3 points that was my actual question.

Comment: Flags are inappropriate for those reasons. You have the ability to vote - use it. If the question is poor, downvote it. When you've earned sufficient privileges, you can vote to close.  Flags should be used only for issues that require a moderator's attention. Don't waste their time for things users themselves can handle.

Comment: Flags aren't inappropriate at all @Ken; if it's a duplicate and you don't have 3k rep then flagging it as a dupe is what that mod message is supposedly telling you to do; repeat for all others

Comment: @Ben: If it's a duplicate, of course flags are appropriate. The question asked what to do if it didn't meet the four points listed, which do *not* include "what if it's a duplicate?". The rest of the text also does not mention "duplicate" anywhere in the content. Read the question asked, and don't assume content is there that is not.

Comment: Yes @Ken, so, if appropriate, you might flag it as "unclear what you're asking" - or whatever - see previous comment I used one simple example to explain that you flagging is fine 'cause I didn't want to write out almost identical text 10 times. Or you might just leave the thing alone.

Comment: @KenWhite If the question was like `How to show line number in Android Studio`, i would simply marked as duplicate. But, here it's different as he posted a question as a reference for future users and answered his own question down.

Comment: @YuvaRaj: I'm not sure what the problem is then. Posting self-answered questions is encouraged here, and while some might need some work there should not need to be flags for them. If you have suggestions for improvements, leave comments or (when possible) edit the question without changing it's meaning. I'm not sure why you want to punish people for trying to share information.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, i'm aware of that & even i posted answer for my question after some solution worked out. But, here it's just not like that because that is not a question itself. Look ken, I'm not trying to punish him. I'm just asking asking whether these posts are allowed or not. You need to read my question again for clear view esp last 3 points.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. Not allowed, as you say, is another matter than not good. Plus, you site that 2 and 3 aren't met but they don't apply to the question. Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @YuvaRaj: You *are* trying to punish, by flagging for a moderator to do something that isn't necessary. Yes, self-answered posts are allowed. No, they're not always perfect, and they sometimes need improvement. The poster at least made an effort to post a question and answer, rather than just a blog post using this site. Instead of flagging, try doing something constructive like editing or commenting to the user suggesting changes. We should be encouraging the proper sharing of information; that is, after all, what all of the [se] sites are designed to do.

Comment: I share Yuva Raj's concerns about the question, I don't think it's a great one and it probably should be closed. But I'd never have dreamed about flagging. Closevoting is the way to go; if you can't do that yet, downvoting and, if one feels that way, commenting are the best options

Comment: @KenWhite When i flagged, the question content was `To save people watching a 'how to' video, I'm posting a quick reference for "How can I show line numbers in Android Studio?" See answer below.` I repeat i don't want anyone to punish. As these kind of posts are rare, i was asking how to deal with that.

Comment: You did not mention *any* of these points in your flag - you only stated that the question was self-answered, which implies that the issue you had with the question was the fact that it was self-answered, and in turn the flag was declined because self-answered questions are acceptable on the site and therefore do not warrant moderator intervention. It has very little to do with whether the content of the question was actionable by regular users, simply because you never addressed the content of the question in your flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that this is not the greatest of questions. You should however not use the custom flag when you can use a different flag instead. One of the strengths of Stack Overflow is that most of the content is moderated by the user base, not by moderators. Moderators are only beamed in for things an other flag can't be used for.

In your case you identified that the question **is likely a duplicate of a different question**. Click 'flag', then 'should be closed...', then choose 'it's a duplicate of...', then paste the link of the question you identified it is a duplicate of. Finally click flag.

If you didn't find a duplicate question, you could attempt to **edit the question** so it is of better quality. Self-answered questions should be formulated as questions too, so you could change it to something like this:

> There are no line numbers showing in my Android Studio. How can I turn
>   on the option to show line numbers in all my files?

If you find that the question is salvageable, you can most likely **flag it to close as "unclear what you are asking"**. If you find that the question is really bad and have no clue what to flag it as, you can always **flag it as "very low quality"**.

In either case, the post will end up in a so-called review queue. People with enough reputation can go through the review queue and pass on their judgement. This happens without intervention of a moderator.

Comment: Ok, i understood.

Comment: @YuvaRaj / Sumurai8 - Sorry to have caused all this discussion. It was simply a case of someone completely new to Android dev not being able to find the answer to a seemingly simple question (without having to watch a youtube video, which was annoying). I have updated it to reflect Sumurai8's point about intelliJ. Please let me know what I should do with this question as I want to help keep the high standards of SO maintained.

Comment: @HockeyJ: It seems that users new to Android dev would find your question useful, however as the OP has mentioned here your question needs to be fleshed out and not simply "I'm just posting an answer here for reference" - and that might be the reason for all the downvotes, rather than the fact that your question is a duplicate (duplicates are useful as signposts, *especially* in situations like this).

Comment: Thank you @BoltClock.